# Namespacing and APC fails

Tags: php, namespaces, apc

I'm trying to use APC with PHP. I've copied the code from the [PHP manual for storing arrays in APC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php); and it works great, as I would expect.

My problem arises when I introduce a namespace when it fails.

```
<?php
namespace tester;

$objs = array();
$objs[] = "123";
$objs[] = "123";
$objs[] = "123";

apc_store('tester:objs', new ArrayObject($objs),60);
$tmp = apc_fetch('tester:objs');
print_r($tmp -> getArrayCopy());
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhhh! I knew it would be something simple! I simple forgot to declare ArrayObject as a global namespace class. Adding a slash in front of ArrayObject worked. Silly me! :(

Working code:

```
<?php
namespace tester;

$objs = array();
$objs[] = "123";
$objs[] = "123";
$objs[] = "123";

apc_store('tester:objs', new \ArrayObject($objs),60);
$tmp = apc_fetch('tester:objs');
print_r($tmp -> getArrayCopy());
exit;
```